# Why does BitBucket not recognize my files as tracked by LFS?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I followed the BitBucket [LFS tutorial](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-git-lfs-with-bitbucket/) and created a repository which contains following `.gitattributes` file:

```
.pdf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
.jpeg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Then I added some PDF and JPEG files.

Then I ran

- `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` and
- `git push origin master`.

I saw no error messages.

However, in the BitBucket web interface I read that there are no files tracked by LFS in my repository.

[image: BitBucket message saying there are no files tracked by LFS in the repository]

What did I do wrong? How can I make sure that BitBucket uses LFS for PDF and JPEG files.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your files are literally named `.pdf`, `.jpeg`, and so forth, you need to adjust the patterns such that they have an asterisk, such as `*.pdf`.  Right now your patterns, while valid, don't match any files in your repository.

Then you need to run `git add --renormalize .` to turn them into LFS files.  If you want to rewrite the history, you should use `git lfs migrate import --everything`  instead with an appropriate `--include` option to rewrite the history of the old version.  If you choose not to, that's fine, but your large files will still be in the history.